# Can I prevent SWF hotlinking with htaccess?

Tags: web-scraping, flash, hotlinking

I have a website with some Flash games. I noticed that someone somehow copied my entire website using an online tool. I was notified by the security I implemented into my server.

It seems this person is using a tool to scrape everything, because I visited his website and saw this on a page: "This file was not retrieved by Teleport Pro, because it was unavailable, or its retrieval was aborted, or the project was stopped too soon."

He/she managed to get all the static content of my website and the SWF of the games. Luckily my files communicate with files from my server in order for the game to start, so he cannot use the games.

I would like to prevent this from being done again in the future. Probably the solution would be to disable SWF hotlinking? If so, I need to know how this can be done using .htaccess or Apache.

I need some advice about what can I possibly do, and if is there a way to protect a website from these scraping tools.

Answer (score 1):

If you require a referrer for your HTML files, that means people will not be able to deep-link to them legitimately from other sites. You can certainly do this for assets, but then any thief worth their salt will know what you have done, and will fake the referrer in order to get the files anyway. This is unfortunately a fairly trivial thing to do, and thus probably not worth your time.

So, the main thing left to do is what you have done already - prevent the Flash applications from starting up unless they can contact your site and obtain permission. It may be worth your looking at some professional AS/Flex libraries for this - I would guess they exist in a commercial form.

Even better, if the games can periodically have a need to access your server, maybe for assets or level maps, you'll give your opponents enough reverse-engineering to make it not worth their while.